# HTML, Embedded Ruby not rendering in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

The main chunk of my blog isn't rendering when I push to Heroku. I've tried a number of things to no avail. I've migrated the database. Heroku Logs says its rendering the page but it shows none of the links, HTML or embedded ruby when I run the app. I think it may have something to with my Articles model. Not sure. Here's what I have. Let me know if you need to see anything else. Thanks

```
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController


  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def index
    @article = Article.all


    @articles = Article.order('created_at DESC')
    @articles_by_month = Article.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC').group_by { |article| article.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
  end


  def month_count
    @articles_by_month = Article.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC').group_by { |article| article.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
  end

  def create  
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

      if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end



  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :image)
  end

end


Model

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader 
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }                 
end
```

Here is the view that isn't rendering at all. The rest of the views(header,footer, etc..) render fine and the links work.

```
<div class="bit-75">

  <% @article.each do |article| %>
    <h2 id="title"><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></h2>
    <br>
    <ul id="article-links">
      <div id="article-image"><%= image_tag article.image_url %></div>
      <br>
      <li id="article-text"><%= article.text %></li>
    <p>Posted on <%= article.created_at %></p>
    <br>


    <% if admin_signed_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to 'Edit',           edit_article_path(article) %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Destroy',        article_path(article),
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %></li>
    <% else %>                
      <li><%= link_to 'Make a Comment', article_path(article) %><p>Comments(<%= article.comments.count %>)</p></li>      
    </ul>
    <% end %>   
  <% end %>

<div id="new-article-path"></div>
</div>
<div class="bit-5">
  <h2>Recent Posts</h2>

    <br>

  <% @article.each do |article| %>

    <ul id="recent-article">
      <li><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></li>
    </ul>

  <% end %>
    <br>
    <br>

  <h2>Archives</h2>

  <% @articles_by_month.each do |monthname, articles| %>
    <h4 id="month-archive"><%=link_to monthname, archives_path %></h4>

    <% end %>



  <!-- <h2>Tags</h2> -->
</div>
```

heroku logs(pretty long)

```
2014-07-02T05:23:23.970096+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (38.9ms)
2014-07-02T05:23:23.974015+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 126ms (Views: 45.5ms | ActiveRecord: 9.5ms)
2014-07-02T05:23:23.972553+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.3ms)
2014-07-02T05:23:40.402197+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/admins" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=bbc86129-9987-4973-9bae-c4421791aa40 fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=197ms status=302 bytes=1222
2014-07-02T05:23:40.209336+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/admins" for 98.16.161.172 at 2014-07-02 05:23:40 +0000
2014-07-02T05:23:40.399492+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 186ms (ActiveRecord: 33.4ms)
2014-07-02T05:23:40.213315+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
2014-07-02T05:23:40.399306+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com/
2014-07-02T05:23:40.213360+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kAMtYWrxZZqh7ozJx2qJS1kYAEA2FH7WnOjAozWyGmU=", "admin"=>{"email"=>"hustada80@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
2014-07-02T05:23:40.495384+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=613ce782-8e68-4d84-b383-f96c7df76f7c fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=2886
2014-07-02T05:23:40.471723+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 98.16.161.172 at 2014-07-02 05:23:40 +0000
2014-07-02T05:23:40.481758+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
2014-07-02T05:23:40.491226+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-07-02T05:23:40.491635+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 10.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
2014-07-02T05:23:40.475645+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2014-07-02T05:23:40.490712+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (7.8ms)
2014-07-02T05:23:40.991172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=de2e4b02-cf09-4dee-801d-8097db86d83f fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=111
2014-07-02T05:35:25+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-07-02T05:35:38+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-07-02T05:35:38.200566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-07-02T05:35:38.015315+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a839f2c by hustada80@gmail.com
2014-07-02T05:35:38.015423+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by hustada80@gmail.com
2014-07-02T05:35:42.300258+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:35:42.300126 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2014-07-02T05:35:44.068316+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:35:44.068183 #2]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:6095 fd=9
2014-07-02T05:35:44.292214+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:35:44.291998 #11]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
2014-07-02T05:35:44.257917+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:35:44.257616 #8]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
2014-07-02T05:35:44.230625+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:35:44.230307 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2014-07-02T05:35:44.277000+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:35:44.276699 #2]  INFO -- : master process ready
2014-07-02T05:35:40.858961+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 6095 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-07-02T05:35:44.547194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-02T05:36:07.326683+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 98.16.161.172 at 2014-07-02 05:36:07 +0000
2014-07-02T05:36:07.547694+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.8ms)
2014-07-02T05:36:07.606733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=42b8f735-dbcf-49c6-934e-929ce7545ede fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=292ms status=200 bytes=2886
2014-07-02T05:36:07.500728+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2014-07-02T05:36:07.599101+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (47.2ms)
2014-07-02T05:36:07.602660+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 102ms (Views: 51.5ms | ActiveRecord: 18.6ms)
2014-07-02T05:36:07.601879+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.6ms)
2014-07-02T05:36:07.931840+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-640666fff5063d0df1cee80215693060.css" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=3deed151-7d47-4e8b-ba0c-6b37d8d3d054 fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=13ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=7311
2014-07-02T05:36:08.065888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-167e763a98f91e4c35869ccad604f596.js" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=66fa4f50-8455-4850-9451-0e5e448dcc0e fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=318312
2014-07-02T05:36:08.710019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=3e1512da-ff1b-40bc-961d-68c2119efc7d fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=196
2014-07-02T05:36:19.248082+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-07-02T05:36:19.248248+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-07-02T05:36:19.246878+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-07-02T05:36:19.248362+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead
2014-07-02T05:36:19.457047+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:36:19.456867 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 11 exit 0> worker=2
2014-07-02T05:36:19.660093+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:36:19.659964 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 8 exit 0> worker=1
2014-07-02T05:36:19.659873+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:36:19.659751 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 exit 0> worker=0
2014-07-02T05:36:19.660443+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:36:19.660210 #2]  INFO -- : master complete
2014-07-02T05:36:18.677579+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-07-02T05:36:21.135150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-02T05:43:02+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-07-02T05:43:13+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-07-02T05:43:14.308749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-07-02T05:43:17.358823+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-07-02T05:43:17.361771+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUITUnicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead
2014-07-02T05:43:17.361830+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-02T05:43:17.358416+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-07-02T05:43:17.765610+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:43:17.765548 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 8 exit 0> worker=1
2014-07-02T05:43:17.764809+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:43:17.764676 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 exit 0> worker=0
2014-07-02T05:43:17.765797+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:43:17.765697 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 11 exit 0> worker=2
2014-07-02T05:43:17.765977+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:43:17.765921 #2]  INFO -- : master complete
2014-07-02T05:43:13.306462+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d4ffe02 by hustada80@gmail.com
2014-07-02T05:43:13.306636+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by hustada80@gmail.com
2014-07-02T05:43:18.442837+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:43:18.442644 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2014-07-02T05:43:20.430574+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:43:20.430372 #11]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
2014-07-02T05:43:20.258723+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:43:20.258571 #2]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:59093 fd=9
2014-07-02T05:43:20.407932+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:43:20.407514 #8]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
2014-07-02T05:43:20.373661+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:43:20.373373 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2014-07-02T05:43:20.418161+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-07-02T05:43:20.417896 #2]  INFO -- : master process ready
2014-07-02T05:43:20.780536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-02T05:43:16.831337+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-07-02T05:43:19.174501+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-02T05:43:17.028772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 59093 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-07-02T05:44:31.538439+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by hustada80@gmail.com
2014-07-02T05:44:36.077537+00:00 heroku[run.5746]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-02T05:44:35.988244+00:00 heroku[run.5746]: Awaiting client
2014-07-02T05:44:38.072012+00:00 heroku[run.5746]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-07-02T05:44:45.389762+00:00 heroku[run.5746]: State changed from up to complete
2014-07-02T05:44:45.375562+00:00 heroku[run.5746]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-02T05:44:57.559180+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=94abc6c3-4e02-4f2b-8551-d3a31450990a fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=208ms status=304 bytes=1110
2014-07-02T05:44:57.358930+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 98.16.161.172 at 2014-07-02 05:44:57 +0000
2014-07-02T05:44:57.506551+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
2014-07-02T05:44:57.555156+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.8ms)
2014-07-02T05:44:57.659011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-640666fff5063d0df1cee80215693060.css" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=d4206d6e-bc79-48a1-be22-15e7997d369f fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=7311
2014-07-02T05:44:57.460053+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2014-07-02T05:44:57.552362+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (42.7ms)
2014-07-02T05:44:57.555722+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 95ms (Views: 46.1ms | ActiveRecord: 21.0ms)
2014-07-02T05:44:57.727072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-167e763a98f91e4c35869ccad604f596.js" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=74356978-8cd9-47ac-92ee-8bfbd6e80929 fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=318312
2014-07-02T05:44:58.358669+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sleepy-wave-3015.herokuapp.com request_id=731e0236-1dd9-4063-915b-6115872df974 fwd="98.16.161.172" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=196
2014-07-02T05:46:47.702096+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:schema:dump && cat db/schema.rb` by hustada80@gmail.com
2014-07-02T05:46:52.946894+00:00 heroku[run.8701]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-02T05:46:53.813517+00:00 heroku[run.8701]: Awaiting client
2014-07-02T05:46:53.845209+00:00 heroku[run.8701]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:schema:dump && cat db/schema.rb`
2014-07-02T05:46:59.773131+00:00 heroku[run.8701]: State changed from up to complete
2014-07-02T05:46:59.758285+00:00 heroku[run.8701]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-02T05:49:25.971374+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bin/rails console` by hustada80@gmail.com
2014-07-02T05:49:30.204777+00:00 heroku[run.1221]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-02T05:49:30.372260+00:00 heroku[run.1221]: Awaiting client
2014-07-02T05:49:30.409488+00:00 heroku[run.1221]: Starting process with command `bin/rails console`
2014-07-02T06:10:46.735678+00:00 heroku[run.1221]: State changed from up to complete
2014-07-02T06:10:46.720594+00:00 heroku[run.1221]: Process exited with status 0
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'


gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'cells'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'


group :doc do

  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'capybara'
end



group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'unicorn'
end
```

Tried running this 'RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile'

Got this in terminal

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile.
```

Comment: Is it working locally? Can you post your heroku logs?

Comment: Certainly. It is working locally. I also added unicorn gem if that makes a difference. It seems to get my apps up and running more often than not.

Comment: Have you made sure that it's precompiling the assets properly? Check: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: I did use this command earlier -> "bundle exec rake assets:precompile, then pushed to git and deployed. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the pg gem. Should I have that here?


group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'unicorn'
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data**

If your HTML / `ruby` embedded code works for other `controller#actions`, you'll likely have an issue with your routing, or how you're structuring your view.

I would do this:

```
$ heroku run rails c
$ Article.create(title: "test, body: "test")
```

This will allow you to create an `Article` record in production, which is going to be a likely cause of your problem (not having the correct dataset)

--

**Routes**

After this has been completed, save and then you need to ensure you're calling the right `controller#action` in your routes. You should have it set using [`resourceful` routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles
```

--

**Model**

Finally, you've overridden the `default_scope` part of your model, but are calling exactly the same conditions when using

```
#app/models/article.rb
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   default_scope ....
end
```

You should remove the `default_scope` reference - you don't need it

---

**Precompile**

The reason your rake precompile doesn't work is because you're not using `PG` locally. Since you're using it in `production`.

To fix this, you just need to include it outside of the `group: production do` block in your `routes` file:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'pg' #-> allows precompile to run for production environment
```

Comment: This probably won't fix your issue, but should help locate a potential issue. If you give me comments, we should be able to fix for you!

Comment: Thanks for that  Rich. The first part of your answer pointed me towards a solution. I had my HTML and all my embedded ruby set up and dependent on an actual article already existing. I sort of did this for admin purposes. So I manually went and created an admin and then used that admin to create an article. Once the article was created everything appeared :). Appreciate the help everyone! Thanks.

Comment: Also, thanks for all the other suggestions with my code. I'm new so any help regardless of a solution is helpful. Thanks